# VS2017 SQLite not writing data to database

Tags: sqlite, dataset, visual-studio-2017, dataadapter

I have the following code which does not throw exceptions, but neither does it update the SQLite database, There are two methods, one which is invoked by the Update button and takes updated data from the GridView control and writes to the SQLite file. Neither actually update the database. In the update method, there are several attempts using different techniques to try to write the data. I included the whole thing for context and as functionality is split into different parts of code. It is using the Metro Framework but I don't think that makes a difference to the database code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using MetroFramework.Forms;
using MetroFramework;

using System.Data.SQLite;


namespace MetroTestApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
    {
        static List<String> entries = new List<string>();
        private BindingSource masterBindingSource = new BindingSource();
        private BindingSource detailsBindingSource = new BindingSource();
        DataSet data = new DataSet();

        static string DbConnectionString = @"Data Source=Emp.db;Version=3;";
        static SQLiteConnection dbc = new SQLiteConnection(DbConnectionString);

        public SQLiteDataAdapter departmentDataAdapter;
        SQLiteDataAdapter empDataAdapter; 

        DataRelation relation;
        SQLiteCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void metroTile1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "OK", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

        private void metroTile2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Stop", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        }

        private void metroGrid2_CellContentClick(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

        private void metroButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  { }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            dbc.Close();
            cmdBuilder.Dispose();
            departmentDataAdapter.Dispose();
            empDataAdapter.Dispose();
            masterBindingSource.Dispose();
            empDataAdapter.Dispose();
            data.Dispose();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

         //   string DbConnectionString = @"Data Source=Emp.db;Version=3;";
         //   using (SQLiteConnection dbc = new SQLiteConnection(DbConnectionString))
                try
                {
                    dbc.Open();

                    departmentDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from DEPARTMENT", dbc);
                    empDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from EMP", dbc);

                    departmentDataAdapter.Fill(data, "DEPARTMENT");
                    empDataAdapter.Fill(data, "EMP");

                    DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("EMPDPEP", data.Tables["DEPARTMENT"].Columns["DEPNO"], data.Tables["EMP"].Columns["DEPNO"]);
                    data.Relations.Add(relation);

                    masterBindingSource.DataSource = data;
                    masterBindingSource.DataMember = "DEPARTMENT";
                    detailsBindingSource.DataSource = masterBindingSource;
                    detailsBindingSource.DataMember = "EMPDPEP";

                    DEPGridView.DataSource = masterBindingSource;
                    EMPGridView.DataSource = detailsBindingSource;

                    DEPGridView.AutoResizeColumns();
                    EMPGridView.AutoResizeColumns();
                }
                catch (SQLiteException ex)
                {
                    MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Stop", ex.Message.ToString(), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                }
        }

        private void metroButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //dbc.Open();

            //departmentDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from DEPARTMENT", dbc);
            //empDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from EMP", dbc);


            SQLiteCommandBuilder cb=new SQLiteCommandBuilder(empDataAdapter);
            empDataAdapter.DeleteCommand = cb.GetDeleteCommand(true);
            empDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand(true);
            empDataAdapter.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand(true);

            SQLiteCommandBuilder cb1 = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(departmentDataAdapter);
            departmentDataAdapter.DeleteCommand = cb1.GetDeleteCommand(true);
            departmentDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = cb1.GetUpdateCommand(true);
            departmentDataAdapter.InsertCommand = cb1.GetInsertCommand(true);

           // MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, cb.GetUpdateCommand().ToString(), "OK", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            empDataAdapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
            departmentDataAdapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            empDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            empDataAdapter.Update(dt);

            data.AcceptChanges();

            empDataAdapter.Update(data, "EMP");
            departmentDataAdapter.Update(data, "DEPARTMENT");
            empDataAdapter.Update(data.Tables["EMP"]);
            departmentDataAdapter.Update(data.Tables["DEPARTMENT"]);


            dt.Dispose();
            cb.Dispose();
            cb1.Dispose();
            dbc.Close();

        }

        private void metroButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dbc.Open();
            DataTable t; t = data.Tables["DEPARTMENT"];
            DataRow newRow;
            newRow = t.NewRow();

            newRow["DEPNO"] = 10; newRow["DEPNAME"] = "GAMES";

            t.Rows.Add(newRow);
            data.AcceptChanges();
            DEPGridView.Refresh();
            dbc.Close();
            t.Dispose();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at this part of your code

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        empDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
        empDataAdapter.Update(dt);
```

You are getting the data and writing it directly back to the database.  If you do not change anything you will not see any changes in the db.  I do not see the point of this code

The the code follows with this

```
        data.AcceptChanges();

        empDataAdapter.Update(data, "EMP");
        departmentDataAdapter.Update(data, "DEPARTMENT");
        empDataAdapter.Update(data.Tables["EMP"]);
        departmentDataAdapter.Update(data.Tables["DEPARTMENT"]);
```

The accept changes marks all the records as not changed. So your DataAdapter.Update will not see any changed records to send to the database. I would move that line of code to after the DataAdapter.Updates and try updating the records again.

```
    empDataAdapter.Update(data, "EMP");
    departmentDataAdapter.Update(data, "DEPARTMENT");
    empDataAdapter.Update(data.Tables["EMP"]);
    departmentDataAdapter.Update(data.Tables["DEPARTMENT"]);

    data.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the problem. It makes sense, as you say, Update() needs to run after the records are changed. And thanks for going through such a large piece of code.